# Wiring up ATX PSU to power (several) 12V LED strips

Tags: power, safety, led-strip, led-driver, atx

(In advance, please pardon my ignorance; I'm still learning)

TL;RD. I want to power N number of 12V LED strips using a PC ATX PSU.
Is it safe & what bits do I need to add to make it function as intended?

Some context:
I'm basing my work on 2 pretty decent articles on the subject:

- https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/connect-led-light-strips-arduino/
- https://learn.adafruit.com/rgb-led-strips?view=all

What I hope to achieve is to control an arbitrary amount of 12V (common anode) LED strips, & from what I can tell they seem to be in the region of 14.4W per metre (x 5m = 72W), based on [*LT12560-RGB* 12V, 60 LEDs @ 4.8 or 14.4 W/mètre x 5 mètre = 24 or 72 Watts and 300 LEDs](https://www.tlc-direct.co.uk/Technical/DataSheets/Skytronic/AVSL_LED_tape_%20guide.pdf), although in the end I'll be going with cheaper units as I need to run close to 16 of these 5 mètre strips concurrently.

I bought some Arduino-friendly MOSFET boards (duinotech *XC-4488*) to do some prototyping before risking frying larger devices (such as the Mega I bought for this project), then some manual bread boarding using NMOS for PoC & testing, but soldering & running 48+ MOSFET is cost-prohibitive & there's probably a better way of achieving this outcome by using an IC, thinking 3x *MAX6971*. 
Effectively I'm making use of them as glorified relays attached to PWM pins.

I've sketched it out via Fritzing & went as far as running a simulation via TinkerCAD (although due to limitations I couldn't recreate it 1:1).

- https://www.tinkercad.com/things/kN1ScLYQq0j-matariki-lights/editel?sharecode=5q0MPWD_CtxPdoZchDBTG-QbR4Et-id8wHuahMLpFvI=

[image: Fritzing sketch for LED array]

& the final build looks like: (keeping it simple, since relevant resistors are build into the MOSFET boards from what I can tell)

[image]

I did some basic tests before firing up & it seemed to have checked out OK, but I was VERY much mistaken, since once I plugged into the ATX PSU, it wasn't long before I got the LOUD POP, flash, magic smoke, funky smell of ozone & the lights went out in the house. 
So I'm unsure if it was my ATX PSU that's faulty, but it seems *far* more likely that I screwed up somewhere.

Needless to say I'm very reticent to pop another ATX, and worry that my invention may be a danger to myself & others. 
Luckily I wasn't running my Arduino from the same PSU via Vin (is that legit?)

I'd really appreciate some help here, as I suspect I'm not officially out of my depth.

Comment: Most atx supplies won't run the 12V unless there is a load on the 5V. Aside from that, your wiring in that picture seems good for test. You wouldn't want 72W going through a breadboard though. Don't know what killed your supply, maybe you shorted something out accidentally?

Comment: Hi @Passerby.  
Thanks for much for the quick ping-back!

A suspicion may be that the ATX was faulty, since it's pretty old & been sitting in a box for a while, but my own limited knowledge seemed more probable.

Noted re the breadboard track, thanks - will wire to the MOSFET board directly.

Re the 5V draw, in theory, once it's all wired up, my Arduino should pick up that load via Vin OK?
In the meantime I'll just put an LED & 10k resistor?

Comment: (also)
Should I have another 10k resistor from +12V to ground?  
A possible suspicion may be that LED strip in there (an off-cut I had, not my final device) may either been popped, not working for  some other reason, and/or the critical threshold was not triggered for it to turn up 7 use the juice.

Comment: These supply use loads in amps, an led or 10k resistor isn't enough.

Comment: Part of my ATX-PSU hacking research had me starting here @   
https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/blog/convert-atx-psu-to-bench-supply.html .  
From what I can, tell I may need to ground +5V with a 5W resistor (between pins 3 & 4)?  
@tony-stewart-older-than-dirt pointed out below that there are a power-ripple in the load (I got this right?). Do I (& if so, what & where?) need to add a capacitor into the mix to smooth it out?

Comment: What is the value of the resistors on the strip?

Comment: @Passerby ATX is the form factor, it does not mean triple output supply.  12V only comes in an ATX enclosure, e.g. https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817339020&ignorebbr=1&nm_mc=KNC-GoogleAdwords-PC&cm_mmc=KNC-GoogleAdwords-PC-_-pla-_-Power+Supplies-_-N82E16817339020&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIv8vWmezI2wIVGbbACh1MaAWIEAYYASABEgJkAfD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds

Comment: Your description is too confusing.  You do not mention what you are trying to accomplish.  You show your prototype using all white LEDs.  You mention 48 transistors (I assume 16 x RGB).   Do you want 16 RGB strips where each R,G, and B LED draws the same current.  Or do you want each RGB LED (or each strip's R,G, & B) to have it own intensity? It is important to know what LEDs you are going to use or the amount of current per LED and the number of LEDs per strip.  It looks like you may want 16 strips with 48 RGB LEDs per meter.   The MAX6971 sources 55 mA / channel much less than 48 MOSFETs.

Comment: Post a photo of ATX PSU with brand P/N and specs

Comment: Also it seems we can no longer assume all ATX supplies behave the same for any switched load we throw at it. SMPS prefer more stable loads unless specifically designed for that.  Instabilities can occur with loose long wires. Next time do a stability test with an 8W light bulb or MOBO and add a low ESR electrolytic or plastic cap to the power input of the MOS power input screw terminals and keep wires paired close together CMOS PWM signal with ground signal and tell us what coded frequency you are using.

Answer (score 3):

72W at 50% PWM on 12V is 36W at some low frequency like 1kHz of AC ripple current which is excessive for most decoupling caps in ATX PSU’s.

If output caps have a dissipation factor which determines what % of load ripple power must be absorbed by the cap.  Aging increases this rapidly.

Although a typical MOBO has dynamic CPU loads the change rate in frequency of load cycles is much lower.

## Conclusion;

Excessive ripple current for YOUR PSU.  Overheated cap, slowly turned into short circuit and faulty circuit protection.  Get a better LED driver supply.

Comment: Thanks for that, @tony-stewart-older-than-dirt.  

(Please bear with with me; I'm a novice, so taking some time to pick up what you're putting down)  

Pushing ripples up to the PSU makes sense, thanks. I recall seeing something akin in the TinkerCAD simulation I created & was unsure how to resolve it, opting to go with how build was indicated in the articles ref'd.  

For smoothing out ripples, is that not what capacitors are for?   
My knowledge re caps are non-existent (so something I'll look up), but in your expertise, what would be appropriate, where & how much?

Comment: All ATX PSU's have OCP with safe shutdown on short circuit. A low ESR cap was missing in the photo to handle current risetime until SMPS can supply the current in xx us. Capable of such high ripple current such as 0.1uF to 1uF Polypropylene or ceramic or any other suitable type on LED driver board. – Choose C much lower  ESR than RdsOn of MOSFET but much bigger C than Coss and FET has much lower RdsOn than ESR of Load

Comment: Those flimsy cables may not be able to triger OCP on 500W+ ATX PSU, even when shorted. Note that may ATX PSU designs also need a minimum load on 3,3 and 5V rails to work properly.

Comment: Agreed @Turbo but that will never cascade faults to line with DC  traces to cause *"the lights {to go} out in the house"*  . Also modern ATX designs dont need a preload to operate.

Comment: Never say never. I can totally see the regulation loop going crazy without any 5V load and blowing up the primary MOSFETs as a result. Just to be clear: That is no supposed to happen, but component failure is quite common in cheap and old ATX PSUs, unfortunately.

Comment: There are at least 3 safety mechanisms that would all have to fail independently before it would turn off the house lights.  I wonder where the corona was ? (ozone)

Comment: @TurboJ There are ATX form factor PSUs with only a 12V output.  ATX does not mean multiple output. With a $20 tag they are not burned in and likely not even tested before they ship. It's a new World, high DOA failure rate and no one cares except those that get a DOA. That's why you see a typical 10% 1 star rating on most products.  The OP did not seem overly concerned the PSU failed.  There is no reason it should have failed. The unit was very likely DOA. See: https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817339020

Comment: I don't buy your failure theory.  But even if, it still should not have gone up in smoke.  The over current protection should have kicked in.  DOA is a much more likely scenario.  Consumers have very low expectations when it comes to products that fail or work substandard.  Now the bean counters rule.  Shipping cost is too high for the consumer to return the product.  And they do not expect repeat customers because they know they sell crap.  Crap sells today.  No burn in or testing keeps costs down.  Apathy keeps the World spinning. The new age apathetic economy with charlatan vendors.